# android to pc bluetooth communication

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, client-server

I need to create an android application that can pair the android device with a windows PC and messages can be passed from android to the PC. 
I want to create it using Java.
Any ideas on how I can implement a client server application to allow for this communication?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `BluetoothChat` example from Android Samples? This gives communication between two devices using Bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that. It was working fine with two android devices. However, was not working with the android and PC. It just wouldn't establish a connection with the PC and when I check the Bluetooth setting it says 'Pair but not connected'

Comment: Also, the bluetooth chat only works if both devices have the application installed. This cannot be installed on the PC therefore, I am unsure of a method to establish a method of communication between the two.

Comment: I used that sample for communication between android mobile and bluetooth module connected to robot. And I can command the robot through my device over bluetooth. I just modified the ID. I think you need to use some kind of software in Windows to enable this.